# Need to speed up MySQL query, it's at 3+ seconds with only 4,000 records, has 3 joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Here's the situation:

I have a few tables (described below) that track residents in an apartment building, their unit number, and when they were "seen" last (we have lots of older people with health issues, so it's important to check on them every 2 days or so; sometimes they die here and that's how we know how to check on them).

The contstraints for a "check" are that they have to have been seen in the past 48 hours; if not, the query should pull their record up. Here are the table definitions I'm using:

The "people" table, where resident info is stored:

```
MariaDB [olin2]> describe people;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fname       | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| lname       | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dob         | date        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| license_no  | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL              |                | 
| date_added  | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| status      | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | Allow             |                |
| license_exp | date        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The "units" table, where unit numbers are stored (people switch units so I didn't want them in the "people" table):

```
MariaDB [olin2]> describe units;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| number   | varchar(3)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| resident | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the "wellness" table, where the "checks" are stored (the resident's id number, when they were seen and by whom, etc.):

```
MariaDB [olin2]> describe wellness;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| wellness_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| people_id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| time_checked | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| check_type   | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| username     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| return_date  | timestamp   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The "return_date" field in the "wellness" table is for when a resident leaves for more than 2 days, then they won't be included in the results when they are displayed (they actually will be included in the query results, but I use PHP to filter those out).

Here's the query I have been using... It worked well for a few weeks, but as there were more and more records added it's been getting noticably slower (right now its 3.5 seconds to return the results):

```
select p.id, w.time_checked, w.username, w.return_date 
from people p 
    left join units u on p.id = u.resident 
    left join wellness w on p.id = w.people_id 
    left join wellness as w2 on w.people_id = w2.people_id 
        and w.time_checked < w2.time_checked
where w2.people_id is null 
    and w.time_checked  < (now() - interval 48 hour)
order by u.number
```

I know my problem is the joins, but I don't know how to get the results I need without them and/or how to optimize this query to speed it up... Here's a sample of results (if needed):

```
+----+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id | time_checked        | username | return_date         |
+----+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
|  8 | 2013-12-01 11:00:13 | tluce    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (3.44 sec)
```

So, in this result set, resident 8 hasn't been seen for 3 days... the result is correct but the 3.44 sec isn't acceptable for my users to have to wait.

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

EDIT (More Info):

I realize updating the wellness entry for each person would be easier and quicker to access; however I like to have these data on-hand because I generate graphs from it to show A) when we most often see a particular resident and B) which staff members check on people the most often (aka - who's doing their job and who's not)

I DO use indexes, and here's the results of an EXPLAIN on my query:

```
 +------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------    -+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len |  ref              | rows | Extra                                                              |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------    -+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             |  107 | Using temporary; Using filesort                                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx   | PRIMARY | 4       | olin2.u.resident |    1 | Using where                                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | w     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 7074 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | w2    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 7074 | Using where; Not exists; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join)     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------    -+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The indexes in the people table: `id, fname, lname, license_no`
The wellness table: `wellness_id`
The units table: `id, number`

Comment: can you run EXPLAIN on this query?

Comment: Sam D: please see my edit for the information you requested.

Comment: Under possible keys each field that has NULL means that index was not used. so you can add index to the fields you use to join. for example units.residents. you can do the same thing to wellness.people_id

Comment: Man that really did the trick, now the query runs in 0.26 seconds... Thanks much! Add that comment as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under possible keys each field that has NULL means that index was not used. so you can add index to the fields you use to join. for example units.residents. you can do the same thing to wellness.people_id –

Answer (score 1):

You have too many joins for this result.  The only reason it seems like you have the "people" table in there is to attach to "units" but you have flags in both "units" and "wellness" that you can join off of.  I also don't believe the second join of the wellness table is necessary.

This is all you should need:

`Select W.people_id, w.time_checked, w.username, w.return_date
FROM units u 
  left join wellness w on u.resident = w.people_id
where w.time_checked  < (now() - interval 48 hour)
order by u.number`

You may want to also look at indexing your people_id fields in tables where it is not the primary key.  That will help speed up any queries you try and run off these tables.

Comment: Thanks, but your query gives me 6208 results, where I was expecting 2. Indexing the fields Sam D. mentioned in his answer/comment fixed it for me, though! I appreciate your help!

Comment: The second join to `wellness` seems to be used to solve a "greatest N per group" problem (it helps to determine `wellness` rows with the max `time_checked` per `people_id`).